# Android bitmap to jpeg without compression

Tags: android, android-bitmap

I wanted to save a bitmap image to a jpeg image on the SD card. Presently I am doing this

```
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream);
```

However this still compresses the image. The source of the image is a DSLR camera connected to the device. The same image needs to be saved on the device without compression.

Is there any way to save as JPEG without compression?

Comment: Simply said: NO. JPEG quality = 100% still does a minimal compression.

Comment: JPEG == compressed, so no.

Comment: So the only option is to use png then?

Comment: jpeg is lossy format by its principle. You need to use png instead.